# How to make javascript variable global

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I need to make this `data` variable global:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "get_data.php",
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            if(my_data.hasOwnProperty(data.results[i].id)) {
                my_data[data.results[i].id].name = data.results[i].name;
            }
        }
    });
```

I want to have this globally declared. Do I need to declare it as array?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Any variable can be "made global" by attaching it as a property of the window.

```
window.data = data;
```

You can now access `data` as a global variable.

Comment: Also useful is `self` in case you don't have access to the DOM, such as from a Web Worker.

Comment: And where do I put that? outside the ajax scope? I tried that but It says that `data` is not defined

Comment: Put it wherever the original `data` variable is.

Comment: can you please give me an example on my posted question. As I have tried and it is not working. I want to use this data variable as in global scope. Please help

Comment: Inside the `success` function, since that's where `data` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable equal to what you wish `data` to be equal to. And when giving `data` its value, reference the variable. Like this:

```
var obj = {};

$.ajax({
    // ....

    data: obj,

    // ....
});
```