# Sending array to popup window with javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code:

```
var my_window=window.open("print.php");
my_window.testValue="some value";
```

In print.php page I have this code:

```
alert(window.testValue);
```

This works in chrome and mozilla but does not work on IE, what might be the problem?

Comment: try use below instead of your code because You can't "pass" the array, but you can make it available as a global (or via a global), and your new page can use something like: var theArray = window.opener.theArray;

Comment: how to make variable global??

Comment: var theArray = window.opener.theArray

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848333/how-do-i-pass-any-array-to-a-window-being-opened-with-window-open

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work, I don't know what I'm doing wrong!!

Comment: WHat error you getting in console?

Comment: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: in parent page I have this javascript code:
 var inputs=$("#content :input[type=text]");
and in the popup page I tried to use this array as follows:
var i=0;
            for(i=0;i<inputs1.length;i++)
            {
                alert(window.opener.inputs[i].value);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in comment using javascript array declare your value as global,

```
window.data = data;
```

as you asked make your variable global please look at [Make Variable as Global JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283732/how-to-make-javascript-variable-global)

And the use below code

`var theArray = window.opener.theArray`

[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5848333/how-do-i-pass-any-array-to-a-window-being-opened-with-window-open)

Hope this helps...

Comment: my array is javascript array not php