# load javascript dynamically and sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, onload

I have 5 different js files which I want to execute after an ajax call success response status.

What I am currently doing is :

```
function require(list, fn)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var newScript = document.createElement('script');
        newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        newScript.src = list[i];
        if (newScript.readyState){  //IE
        newScript.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (newScript.readyState == "loaded" ||
                newScript.readyState == "complete"){
                newScript.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
          };
        } else {  //Others
          newScript.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
      }

      newScript.src = url;
      headID.appendChild(newScript);
    }
}
```

Let's say I have file1.js,file2.js,file3.js . I have a variable dca declared on file2.js which I want to use for some operations in file3.js.
For that I need to load file1.js,file2.js sequentially . But unfortunately, this is not happening in the method that I am using.

Please help how to achieve this goal.

I even tried with

```
addEventListeners('load',function({ //some operations }));
```

but to no effect.

Comment: you can define it in <head><script> var dca;</script></head>

Comment: if you need them all to load first use promises or a loader like require.js

Comment: _"have a variable dca declared on file2.js"_ Is `dca` a global variable ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const require = ([head, ...tail]) => {
  const loadScript = link => new Promise((fulfill, reject) => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.addEventListener('load', fulfill);
    script.addEventListener('error', reject);
    script.src = link;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  });
  loadScript(head).then(() => {
    if (tail.length > 0) {
      require(tail);
    }
  });
};
```

I hope that code is self-explaining.

Also make sure that `dca` variable is [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283732/how-to-make-javascript-variable-global).